# Evaluating the complex analysis integral by parametrization

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Evaluating the integral below

$\int_\gamma \sqrt{z}dz \;$ where $\gamma =\{z\in C : \lvert z\rvert = 3$}

I think I've some mistakes. Can you check my process and tell me where do I have a mistake or mistakes?

I parameterized by thinking it is a circle;

z(t) = 3$e^{it}$ and i thought t: 0 $\le t\le2\pi$

But I do not know the direction is counterclockwise or not that would change the parameterization sign

$$\int_\gamma f(z)\mathrm dz:=\int_a^b \gamma'(t) f(\gamma(t))\mathrm dt.$$

**$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{3e^{it}}3\mathrm i3e^{it}dt$$**

I did not write the rest of the integral calculations. I just need to find out where do I have a mistake So I can move on by that. Thank you.

Comment: Welcom to MSE. Before telling us how you did it, you should tell us what does $\sqrt z$ mean.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos First of all thank you. Isn't it a square root? That is how I understood actually.

Comment: There exist two square roots of an element in an integral domain. But in this case, there is no sense of positive or negative. Thus you need to define what the notation $\sqrt{z}$ means. You need to define the principal square root.

Also, the direction of the contour should be specified in the problem. If not, you should probably assume that it is counterclockwise.

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{3e^{it}}\color{red}{3}\mathrm i3e^{it}dt$. Erase the $\color{red}{\tt red}$ one.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 3}\root{z}\,\dd z & =
-\int_{-3}^{0}\root{-x}\expo{\ic\pi/2}\dd x
-\int_{0}^{-3}\root{-x}\expo{-\ic\pi/2}\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
-\ic\int_{0}^{3}\root{x}\dd x
+\pars{-\ic}\int_{0}^{3}\root{x}\dd x =
\left. -2\ic\,{x^{3/2} \over 3/2}\,\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ 3} =
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{-4\root{3}\ic} \\ &
\end{align}